# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , what is the solution for below error?

Tags: android, app-store

we are releasing our app in playstore. it was rejecting continuously by google. we are getting below response from google

> We’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app bundle
> version 32 is not compliant with Google Play Policy. We’ve included
> details below about the specific issue with your app and what you can
> do to get your app on Google Play.
>
> Step 1: Fix the policy issue with your app
>
> During review, we found that your app violates the Malware and User
> Data policy. We detected that your app currently contains spyware code
> that transmits personal data off the device without adequate notice or
> consent.
>
> Issue with your app:
>
> Your app is uploading users' Image information but the privacy policy
> does not meet the policy requirements.
>
> The privacy policy in the designated field in the Play Console is
> inadequate because
>
> It does not disclose the types of personal and sensitive user data
> your app accesses, collects, uses, and shares (such as: Image ) Action
> Required:
>
> Update the privacy policy in the Play Console to address the issue
> identified above. Learn more about privacy policy requirements on the
> User Data policy page. Before resubmitting your app for further
> review, please make sure to deactivate the non-compliant app bundle
> version 32 and increment the version code of the app bundle in the
> Production track.
>
> You can read through the User Data policy for more details and
> examples of common violations.
>
> Step 2: Submit an update with the increased version number to your app
>
> Go to your Play Console. Select the app. Go to App bundle explorer.
> Select the non-compliant APK/app bundle's App version at the top right
> dropdown menu, and make a note of which releases they are under. Go to
> the track with the policy issue. It will be one of these 4 pages:
> Internal / Closed / Open testing or Production. Near the top right of
> the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage
> track first) If the release with the violating APK is in a draft
> state, discard the release. Add the policy compliant version of app
> bundles or APKs. The non-compliant version of app bundles or APKs is
> under the "Not included" section of this release. For further
> guidance, please see the "Not included (app bundles and APKs)" section
> in this Play Console Help article. The new release is rolled out 100%
> and completely deactivates the non-compliant APK. To save any changes
> you make to your release, select Save. When you've finished preparing
> your release, select Review release. If the non-compliant APK is
> released to multiple tracks, repeat steps 5-9 in each track.
>
> Kindly note that your changes aren't sent for review automatically.
> You must go to the Publishing overview page and click Send for review
> to submit your changes.
>
> For additional information, please visit the Developer Program
> Policies and the Play Console Help Center.
>
> Thanks for working with us to fix the policy issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't disclose the user data that you are collection through your app in the privacy policy.

You would think that the user knows that your'e collecting some non-important data and you wouldn't need to mention it, but you have to disclose any and all you collect from users in the policy.

The following steps might help - Change your privacy policy, include all the details you are collecting from the user.

- Then create an update.

  - update `versionCode` in `build.gradle (:app)`
- Publish the new APK

I think this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Data Safety form is filled and submitted to review.
Go to Google Play Console > select your app -> scroll down to Policy and Programs in the left menu > App Content.
There you could find the Data Safety form and mark what data is collected and shared.